# convert to Mono<List<String>> from Flux<List<String>> in Java

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have this entity class.

```
public class MyClass {

    private String category;

    private List<String> topics;

}
```

I am using firestore database with spring reactive. I am trying to return all topics from all categories in a list in a controller but getting an empty list return. Here is my controller method. Here 'getTopics' return a list of topics.

```
 @GetMapping("/alltopics")
 public Mono<List<String>> getAllTopics() {
     List<String> topics = new ArrayList<>();
     repository.findAll().map(MyClass::getTopics).subscribe(topics::addAll);
     return Mono.just(topics);
    }
```

Comment: Try `return repository.findAll().flatMap(value -> { return Mono.just(value.getTopic()); } ).collectList();` and skip the subscribe, the calling client subscribes, not you.

Comment: That returns a Mono<List<List<String>>>. I am trying to return Mono<List<String>>.

Comment: Then please be more clear in your question about what your return types are as you have not written them out. You have `MyClass::topics` but what does `getTopic` return as this infers a single topic and not a list of topics.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. Can you help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Project Reactor documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#which.values) is really good. You want to aggregate a `Flux`; I suggest using `reduce()`, something like

```java
import java.util.stream.Collector;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;

...

@GetMapping("/alltopics")
public Mono<List<String>> getAllTopics() {
    return repository.findAll()
            .map(MyClass::getTopics)
            .reduce(new LinkedList(),
                (result, topics) -> {
                    result.addAll(topics));
                    return result;
                });
}
```